# How can I get every second element if each is embedded in another one?

Tags: css

```
<div class="question_container">
    <div class="views">
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
<div class="question_container">
    <div class="views">
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
<div class="question_container">
    <div class="views">
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
```

How can I style every second class views in pure css.

In jquery I would do

```
$('*[class=views]:even').addClass('views');
```

But how can I do this CSS?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child` property for this:

Example:

```
.question_container:nth-child(2n) .views{
    color: red;
}
```

`:nth-child(2)` would select **only** the second item, while `:nth-child(2n)` will select **every** second item.

Comment: Actually I think your code would only style one (the second) element, but the OP asked for **every** second element and therefor the CSS should be: `.question_container:nth-child(2n) .views`

Comment: @sandeep thanks, it worked with Andrej 2n not 2. Change that and I'l accept. Thanks for your help

Comment: In fairness to @Truth, those `div`s are not closed in the original question. Fixing it...

Comment: @yehudda is this solution working for you? if yes - could you please share a fiddle?

Comment: @Dipaks: Of course it fails in IE8. That browser does not support `:nth-child()`.

Comment: @Dipaks nth-child is not work in IE8 & below. For IE you can use http://selectivizr.com/ js

Comment: @Dipaks Yes it does fail. Why? Checkout the [browser support](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) for `nth-child`.

Comment: Would the best thing to do for ie8 is to set it with jQuery after the page has loaded

Comment: @Andrej just to know - If it fails in IE8 and I don't believe anyone doesn't want support for IE8. Instead of using Selectivizr how bad it would be using jquery ':odd'?

Comment: @Dipaks I dont see any problems using javascript, but the OP asked for a CSS only method.

Comment: @Dipaks it takes a second to load in JS

Comment: @yehuda But adds one additional server round trip :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `:nth-child` selector with the `even` keyword.

```css
.question_container:nth-child(even) .views{
    /* styles for every second class */
}
```

I would not use `:nth-child(1n)` nor `:nth-child(2n)` for the trivial cases of selecting odd or even children. Although these are perfectly valid, they are less clear than the keywords `odd` and `even`; especially for people who don't work with CSS on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrej and @sandeep said, it does work:

```
<style>
.question_container:nth-child(2n) .views{
    color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="question_container">
    <div class="views">
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
<div class="question_container">
    <div class="views">
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
<div class="question_container">
    <div class="views">
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxmqc1au/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make the box to be have half the widht (50%) ?
Having them floated to the left and then clear will be the best solution

HTML:

```
<div class="legend-box">
  <div class="box"> [] box 1 </div>
  <div class="box"> [] box 2 </div>
  <div class="box"> [] box 3 </div>
  <div class="box"> [] box 4 </div>
  <div class="box"> [] box 5 </div>
  <div class="box"> [] box 6 </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r5xq9von/